# Reading an Exported Javascript Object in Python

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

Is it possible to read/parse an exported Javascript or Typescript JSON-like object in Python?
For example:

**In myJava.js:**

```
export const myObj = {
   entry: val
   entry2: val2
   ...
}
```

**In parseJava.py:**

```
def parseJava():
    # Some code to read in the javascript object
    javaObjAsDictionary = someFunction("myJava.js")
```

Does such a "someFunction()" exist? If not, are there any clean ways around this? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import esprima
# with open("yourfile.js", "r") as f:
#    source_code = f.read()
source_code="""
export const myObj = {
   entry: val,
   entry2: val2
}"""
ast = esprima.parseModule(source_code)
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to parse JSON, there is a [library called JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) in Python 2 and 3 that does the encoding and decoding.

Specifically, you can use the `json.loads` or `json.load` methods to get a Python object (dictionary/list) from your JSON.

Something like:

```
import json
jsonDict = json.load("myJSON.json")
```

I am not sure exactly if this is what you need, hope this gives you a start.

Answer (score -4):

```
# following code assumes that 'data.json' file exists in the current working directory

with open('data.json', 'r') as jsonFile: # opens JSON file in read only mode

    # loads the content of JSON file and converts it into python dictionary object

    dictionary = json.load(jsonFile)

    print(dictionary)
```